# Easy solution for array of passwords/usernames that can be used throughout different activities of app

Tags: java, android

I have this android app project due tonight (lord help me) and it requires a user login and account creation. I was looking into using SQLite for this and it is coming along, but I realized I'm running out of time. I would love to just make an ArrayList of usernames and passwords that can be globally accessed, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about android programming to know how to do that or if it is even possible. I really need help with this. Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Comment: use sharedPrefernaces to store array and retrive it when needs

Answer (score 2):

considering the fact that you wanted to use the DATABASE for your project and you dont know much of programming stuff, I have created this small Application for you using  ***realm.io***  
Realm is a database for mobile application and very easy to implement.

Just download the complete code in your android studio and you are good to go :) 
Code is very simple and easy to understand with the basic knowledge of programming.

**In build.gradle :**
 *compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'*  
paste this under dependencies { ... } and sync your project.

[click here to download the project](https://bitbucket.org/sohaib_karim/userlogin-realm.io/downloads)

Answer (score 1):

use [shared preference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

**define it in your activity**

```
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username", "joey tribbiani");
 editor.putString("password", "joey doesn't share food!!!");
    editor.commit();
```

**use it anywhere**

```
   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String username= sharedpreferences.getStringExtra("username","defaultvalue");
 String password= sharedpreferences.getStringExtra("password","defaultvalue");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make set and get methods for username & password in Custom Application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

 private static MyApplication mApp = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mApp = this;         
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
     return mApp;
    }
}
```

and also define custom application class name in manifest file

```
<application
            android:name=".MyApplication "/>
```

From any class call MyApplication.getInstance.anymethod().